# how to encode/ change the format of existing json to another using angular/javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

here i m having a  json in below format

**Present Format**

```
 {
  "info": {
    "laptop": {
    },
    "config": {
      "properties": {
        "ram": {
        },
        "processor": {
        },
        "hdd": {

        }
      }
    },
    "link": {

    },
    "name": {

    },
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "model": {

        },
        "maker": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "enterprise": {

        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

i am using some plugin like ngx-tree, primeng plugins for which data needs to be in different format  like below

**Required Format**

```
  [
        {
          name: 'laptop',

        },
        {
          name: 'config',
          children: [
            { name: 'ram', children: [] },
            { name: 'processor' },
            {name:'hdd'}
          ]
        },
         {
          name: 'link',
          children: []
        },
        {
          name: 'name',
          children: []
        },

        {
          name: 'company',
          children: [
            { name: 'model' },
            { name: 'maker' },
            { name: 'country' },
            { name: 'enterprise' }

          ]
        }
      ];
```

now my issue is how can i change my data from the present format to required format ? is there any suggestion so that i can make that change

Comment: can you update the required format clear?

Comment: @Harish now it is updated please check

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively walk over the input object to map it to the required format with something like this:

```
  function recursiveConvert(input) {
     let converted = []

     for(i in input){
       converted.push({
         name: i,
         children: []
       })

       if(input[i].properties) {
          converted[converted.length - 1].children.push(recursiveConvert(input[i].properties)) 
       }
     }

     return converted
  }
```

If you want no empty children arrays simply change it to:

```
function recursiveConvert(input) {
     let converted = []

     for(i in input){
       converted.push({
         name: i
       })

       if(input[i].properties) {
          let lastInsert = converted[converted.length - 1]

          lastInsert.children = [recursiveConvert(input[i].properties)]
       }
     }

     return converted
  }
```

be sure to call it with `recursiveConvert(myInput.info)` since it doesn't expect that wrapper object.

Comment: based on our input i created this stack link please check but im not able to get any log  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yljwzd

Comment: Like I said call it with this.recursiveConvert(this.data.info), it's not expecting the wrapping info object

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const json = {"info": {"laptop": {},"config": {"properties": {"ram": {},"processor": {},"hdd": {}}},"link": {},"name": {},"company": {"properties": {"model": {},"maker": {"type": "integer"},"country": {"type": "text"},"enterprise": {}}}}};
const result = Object.keys(json.info).map(k => ({
  name: k,
  children: json.info[k].properties
    ? Object.keys(json.info[k].properties).map(kk => ({name: kk}))
    : []
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can it work on n number child ? i mean suppose if a key has nested children and in that also we have nested children

Comment: You can do it recursively by keeping track of the current object and check if has children..

Comment: i mean like this   {
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { name: 'child1' },
        { name: 'child2', children: [
          { name: 'grandchild1' },
          { name: 'grandchild2' }
        ] }
      ]
    }
  ];   ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one line, purely functional solution:

```js
const input = {
  "info": {
    "laptop": {
    },
    "config": {
      "properties": {
        "ram": {
        },
        "processor": {
        },
        "hdd": {

        }
      }
    },
    "link": {

    },
    "name": {

    },
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "model": {
          "properties": {
            "apple": {},
            "banana": {},
            "pear": {}
          }
        },
        "maker": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "enterprise": {

        }

      }
    }
  }
}

const convert = input => Object
  .entries(input)
  .map(([name, value]) => ({
    name,
    children: convert(value.properties || {})
  }))

console.log(convert(input.info));
```

Here's an es2015 version:

```
function convert(input) {
  return Object.keys(input).map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      children: convert(input[name].properties || {})
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: can it work on n number child ? i mean suppose if a key has nested children and in that also we have nested children

Comment: it uses es 2017 right is it possible with es 6 or 5 bcoz  in my application it is  giving errors